# Use Applescript to create filtered table in Numbers

Tags: numbers, applescript

Trying to figure out how to get Applescript to evaluate cells only in a certain row, and copy data to another table based on said evaluation.

I have a table with two rows, with the data to be evaluated in column B. If the cell does not contains an asterisk, a string is created with the cell value, and each following cell is added to string as long as not an asterisk.

At the asterisk, I would like the corresponding A valueTo be entered into a new row on another table, as well as the preceding A value (so if B3, A3 and A2 and copied), as well as the string.

Been a long day, so sure did not make sense. Here is an example (names are changed)

[Current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wm76o.png)

[Desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Irmce.png)

Thanks for any help can provide. These are legal depositions and I've been tasked with subtitling them. The numbers are the corresponding time stamps after doing so work arounds with the provided transcript and Premiere pro.  I have already created working subtitles, but have been asked to have the line breaks follow the official transcript. In this case only need timestamp for first and last word of lines. Was able to leave * in the data to keep track of the line breaks, but struggling in capturing desired line breaks and string in new entry.

How it comes from the court (lined like this, 1-25 every page), which I though was best to replace with *:"

5   This deposition is being taken on April 29th,
 6   2020, at 10:00 a.m., in the matter of Batman versus Gotham
 7   Police Dept, et al.
 8   This case is venued in the Gotham
 9   Superior Court, Case Number

And if think can accomplish in Numbers that would be awesome. Been able to isolate the values in a related table, but can't collapse out empty cells without messing up the relationships.

Probably could copy to new table with cell values and delete empty rows, but since have 18 depositions with average length of 2.5 hrs trying to automate at every chance possible.